# Colorado potato beetle diet

Tags: entomology, food, nomenclature

The Colorado potato beetle is best known for being a potato pest. However, I've just learned that it originates from Northern America and the potato itself comes from South America.

So the question is, what did potato beetles eat before they were introduced to potatoes?

Comment: Other Solanacae, in particular buffalo-bur — http://entomology.ifas.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/leaf/potato_beetles.htm#hosts — although the time period between discovery and potato was quite short.

Comment: I see, so the hosts were likely other members of the same family and not some completely different plant?

Comment: Basically, yeah.  This is a wolves-to-dogs thing, not a wolves-to-humans (bad analogy).

Comment: Please convert your first comment to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They ate other [Solanaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae) species.  [This University of Florida info page](http://entomology.ifas.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/leaf/potato_beetles.htm) gives an excellent overview of the species, including its hosts (emphasis mine):

> Potatoes are the preferred host for the Colorado potato beetle, but it may feed and survive on a number of other plants in the family Solanacae, including belladonna, common nightshade, eggplant, ground cherry, henbane, horse-nettle, pepper (rarely), tobacco, thorn apple, tomato, and its **first recorded host plant: buffalo-bur**.

The naming history is a bit weird — being neither originally from Colorado or associated with potatoes — but hey, that's science.

Comment: That for the fun fact about the name :)